# How to split string into alphabetic and numeric components?

Tags: php

I have used this. But it doesn't work because there are special characters. How to split string into alphabetic and numeric components?

```
list($var1, $var2) = sscanf('page-1', '%[a-z]%[0-9]);
```

Comment: `list($var1, $var2) = explode('-', 'page-1');`

Comment: but I should split it into alphabetic and numeric components

Comment: You can use a numeric string as a number almost anywhere in PHP. If that is an issue, you can always use `$var2 = (int)$var2;`